# Wildcards in variable path with Powershell

Tags: powershell, wildcard

I would like in my script to use wildcard in variable like this :

```
$TARGET = "\\MACHINE1\c$\ProgramData\Test\12.*\Data\"
```

The problem is $TARGET returns

```
\\MACHINE1\c$\ProgramData\Test\12.*\Data\
```

and not

```
\\MACHINE1\c$\ProgramData\Test\12.1.1.1\Data\
```

However

```
Test-Path "\\MACHINE1\c$\ProgramData\Test\12.*\Data\"

=> TRUE
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: The question is : How can I write in the variable $TARGET the correct path without the wildcard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `Get-ChildItem` to retrieve the real path:

```
$TARGET = "\\MACHINE1\c$\ProgramData\Test\12.*\Data\"
Get-ChildItem $Target


    Directory: \\MACHINE1\c$\ProgramData\Test\12.1.1.1

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        10-10-2014     12:48            data
```

Comment: Is it possible to save it in a variable ?

Comment: $TARGET = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\MACHINE1\c$\ProgramData\Test\12.*\Data\"

Answer (score 16):

The Best in this cases IMO is using Resolve-Path,

```
$TARGET = Resolve-Path "\\MACHINE1\c$\ProgramData\Test\12.*\Data\" | Select -ExpandProperty Path
```